# Telerik RadCombobox - Using templated combobox with checkboxes puts checkbox on top of each row

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

i'm following the demo here
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx#qsf-demo-source

works well but when i set

`CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="True"`

the check box does not appear in the same line as each item row, instead it appears on top of each item (2 rows for each item, 1st row shows the check box, 2nd row shows the actual item). The total number of rows appearing in the dropdown becomes item count x 2.

[checkbox]

[item]

[checkbox]

[item]

What can I do to make the check box appear on the same row as the item?

Thanks for reading

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. Can you please check that any other style applied to your checkbox?

Comment: I think you should change the width of your combobox :)

Comment: Can you show  me your code ?